# Converting C# game development codes from PC to android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game for the PC and trying to get it to work on android as well. But I am having trouble with some of my C# codes. The game works fine on the PC, but when I build it for the android(apk) and transfer it to the mobile, the character will not move. I can only use the fire/ shoot function. Below are the codes used on the character:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class player: MonoBehaviour
{
private bool _faceRight;
private control_mainchar2D _control;

private float _normalizedxspeed;

public float speed_max = 4;
public float speedacceleration_onground = 10f;
public float speedacceleration_inair = 5f;
public float ShootRate;

public int Full_Health = 100;

public GameObject Damege_Effct;
public GameObject ShootProjectileEffects;

public Projectiles Projectiles;
public Transform ProjectilesShootDirection;


//Animator
public Animator Animation;

//Audio
public AudioClip Player_FireSfx;
public AudioClip Player_DamageSfx;
public AudioClip Player_HealSfx;


public int Health { get; private set; }

public bool Act_Dead { get; private set; }

public float _ableShootIn;

//private Collider2D _collider2D;

//public void Start()
//{
//    _collider2D = GetComponent<Collider2D>();

//}

public void Awake()
{
    _control = GetComponent<control_mainchar2D>();
    _faceRight = transform.localScale.x > 0;
    Health = Full_Health;
}

public void Update()
{
    _ableShootIn -= Time.deltaTime;

    if (!Act_Dead)
        Control_Input();

    var movementFactor = _control.State.IsGrounded ? speedacceleration_onground : speedacceleration_inair;

    if (Act_Dead)
        _control.Set_ForceX(0);

    else
        _control.Set_ForceX(Mathf.Lerp(_control.Velocity.x, _normalizedxspeed * speed_max, Time.deltaTime * movementFactor));

    Animation.SetBool("ActLanded", _control.State.IsGrounded);
    Animation.SetBool("ActDeath", Act_Dead);
    Animation.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(_control.Velocity.x) / speed_max);
}

public void FinishLevel()
{
    enabled = false;
    _control.enabled = false;
    GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = false;
}

public void Death()
{
    _control.Control_Collisions = false;
    GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = false;
    Act_Dead = true;
    Health = 0;

    _control.Set_Force(new Vector2(0, 20));
}

public void Respawn_Area(Transform spawn_Point)
{
    if (!_faceRight)
        Flip();

    Act_Dead = false;
    GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = true;
    _control.Control_Collisions = true;
    Health = Full_Health;

    transform.position = spawn_Point.position;
}

public void Receive_Damage (int damage, GameObject instigator)
{
    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(Player_DamageSfx, transform.position);
    TextFloat.Show(string.Format("-{0}", damage), "PlayerReceivedDamageText", new TextPositionerInGWPoint(Camera.main, transform.position, 2f, 60f));

    Instantiate(Damege_Effct, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    Health -= damage;

    if (Health <= 0)
        LevelManager.Instance.Player_Death();
}

public void AwardHealth(int health, GameObject instigator)
{
    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(Player_HealSfx, transform.position);
    TextFloat.Show(string.Format("+ {0}!", health), "HealthAwardText", new TextPositionerInGWPoint(Camera.main, transform.position, 2f, 60f));
    Health = Mathf.Min(Health + health, Full_Health);
}

private void Control_Input()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        _normalizedxspeed = 1;
        if (!_faceRight)
            Flip();
    }

    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        _normalizedxspeed = -1;
        if (_faceRight)
            Flip();
    }

    else
    {
        _normalizedxspeed = 0;
    }

    if (_control.Able_Skip && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        _control.Skip();
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        ShootProjectile();

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F))
        ShootProjectile();
}

private void ShootProjectile()
{
    if (_ableShootIn > 0)
        return;

    if (ShootProjectileEffects != null)
    {
        var effect = (GameObject) Instantiate(ShootProjectileEffects, ProjectilesShootDirection.position, ProjectilesShootDirection.rotation);
        effect.transform.parent = transform;
    }

    var direction = _faceRight ? Vector2.right : -Vector2.right;

    var projectiles = (Projectiles)Instantiate(Projectiles, ProjectilesShootDirection.position, ProjectilesShootDirection.rotation);
    projectiles.Initialize(gameObject, direction, _control.Velocity);

    //projectiles.transform.localScale = new Vector3(_faceRight ? 1 : -1, 1, 1);

    _ableShootIn = ShootRate;


    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(Player_FireSfx, transform.position);

    Animation.SetTrigger("Shoot");
}

private void Flip()
{
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(-transform.localScale.x, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
    _faceRight = transform.localScale.x > 0;
}
}
```

Will I have to revamp the whole code to get it to work on touch screen mobile devices/ tablets or can I just change the inputs under the Control_Input() method (If so how can I go about that)?

Comment: Since monogame is crossplatform, you can simply add a method that handles the user input and add that to your code without removing anything.

Comment: I tried implementing a method to include (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
       {
            _normalizedxspeed = 1;
            if (!_faceRight)
                Flip();
        } But it didn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Platform #define directives](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html)

Change your `Control_Input()` function to this

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID
private void Control_Input()
{
    if (Input.GetTouch(0).position.x > Screen.width / 2.0f) //If touched right part of screen
    {
        _normalizedxspeed = 1;
        if (!_faceRight)
            Flip();
    }

    else if (Input.GetTouch(0).position.x < Screen.width / 2.0f) //If touched left part of screen
    {
        _normalizedxspeed = -1;
        if (_faceRight)
            Flip();
    }

    else
    {
        _normalizedxspeed = 0;
    }

    if (_control.Able_Skip && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        _control.Skip();
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        ShootProjectile();

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F))
        ShootProjectile();
}
#else
private void Control_Input()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        _normalizedxspeed = 1;
        if (!_faceRight)
            Flip();
    }

    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        _normalizedxspeed = -1;
        if (_faceRight)
            Flip();
    }

    else
    {
        _normalizedxspeed = 0;
    }

    if (_control.Able_Skip && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        _control.Skip();
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        ShootProjectile();

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F))
        ShootProjectile();
}
#endif
```

Haven't tested but I think it should work.

Comment: @AdrianAndrews Don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer if it solved your problem.